# Why does the result of query_map not print anything?

Tags: rust

I would like to catch a SQLite null result and properly print a message or the result.

I prepare a statement, extract the result to `MyStruct`, check if the result is `Some` or `None` (null) and if it's `Some` print result in the for loop.

This code properly matches `Some` or `None` but does not print anything:

```
let mut stmt = conn.prepare(&query).expect("execute error");
let mut rows = stmt.query_map(&[&par_a, &par_b], |row| {
    MyStruct {
        a: row.get(0),
        b: row.get(1),
        c: row.get(2),
    }
}).expect("query_map error");

match rows.next() {
    Some(_x) => {
        println!("Some");
        for result in rows {
            println!("{:?}", result.unwrap());
        }
    }
    None => println!("The result is empty. Try again."),
}
```

If I remove all the `match` statements and put only this print in loop everything works properly:

```
for result in rows {
     println!("{:?}", result.unwrap());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are *throwing away the result of the iterator*:

```
match rows.next() {
    Some(_x) => {
```

That `_x` means "I want to ignore this variable, compiler, don't complain about it". Except you **don't want to ignore it**.

```
Some(row) => {
    println!("Some");
    println!("{:?}", row.unwrap());
}
```

Comment: @twistezo You are only calling `next` once, *so you only get one result*. I'm unclear why you think you would get multiple. I'd highly recommend re-reading [*The Rust Programming Language*, second edition](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/second-edition/), specifically the [chapter on control flow](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/second-edition/ch03-05-control-flow.html) (esp. `loop`) and [the chapter on iterators](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/second-edition/ch13-02-iterators.html). Your original code already looped over everything (`for result in rows`).